# OpenVR Unity Render Sprite in One Eye

Tags: unity-game-engine, openvr, htc-vive

Is there a way to render a sprite in just one eye, while it is invisible through the other eye? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't have unity, but if you have access to the source of the openvr (plugin? that's what they are for ue4) just change where it calls submit() to both eyes and add the graphics layer as public so you can expose it in unity. Then you would just override your camera with that method and manually draw it to a certain eye, you could even have two layers so you can specify which eye you want specific stuff to go to.

Comment: @Dispersia There is an option to assign each eye to a different camera, and by default with the prefab it's set to `both` but when I choose a different camera for `left` and `right` eyes, Unity crashes when I run it.

Comment: I would have suggested a RightEye layer and LeftEye layer, then two separate cameras with different layer masks - but if Unity is crashing with separate eye cameras, then that wouldn't work until that's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I have this setup and this renders a single canvas stretched on the whole screen on top of the eyes:

[image]

**Edit:** I'm using Google Cardboard SDK but the principle should be all the same